# Surface Area of unit n-sphere covered by rotating a unit vector around a fixed unit vector such that angle between the two vectors is always fixed.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, analytic-geometry

Consider an n-dimensional unit sphere and unit vector from the origin with its tip lying on the surface of sphere. Consider another vector which makes some angle say $\epsilon$ with unit vector. From a 3-dimensional analogy, if we rotate this vector around fixed vector so that angle between two vectors is always constant, we'll get some portion of the area of the sphere covered.

I want to know if there exists some explicit formula for computing such area given $\epsilon$ for an n-dimensional sphere. If not then how should we go about calculating this.

Comment: See this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1305399/59379). For the unit $d$-sphere embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{d+1}$, the "surface area" you seek (i.e the "area" of the union of circular arc segments when you change one of the endpoint) is $\frac{2\pi^{d/2}}{\Gamma(\frac{d}{2})} \int_0^\epsilon (\sin\phi)^{d-1} d\phi$.

Comment: Well thanks a lot @achillehui for your valuable comment and thanks Samrat for the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "area" you are looking for is in fact an $n-1$ dimensional object, as a sphere in $n$ space is an $n-1$ dimensional shell and you are cutting off a piece of it.    If you mean to imply that $\epsilon$ is very small, the piece will be an $n-1$ dimensional ball.  The analogy with a sphere in 3D is applicable-the piece you cut off is almost a circle because you can't see the curvature of the original sphere.  If your fixed vector is along the $x$ axis, the boundary of the cut off piece will be $y^2+z^2+w^2+\dots = \epsilon^2$, with $n-1$ terms on the left.  The $n-1$ [dimensional volume is then](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_of_an_n-ball)  $\frac {\pi^{(n-1)/2}}{\Gamma(\frac n2-1)}\epsilon^{n-1}$

Comment: Thanks @Ross Millikan. Your answer really helped !